# css not showing up in calender after adding ajax controls

Tags: php, css, ajax

I'm trying to make a calender in php, i have done the first part and have the layout and information, i am trying to add a previous and next month now and the css has gone for some reason. I am following a tutorial

The only info that shows is the previous and next month button and the current month. I have all three files in the htdocs folder of xampp. I dont know whats wrong :(

here is the file to view everything

show_calendar.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="calCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar(){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
showmonth = month;
showyear = year;
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function next_month(){
var nextmonth = showmonth + 1;
if (nextmonth > 12) {
   nextmonth = 1;
   showyear = showyear + 1;
 }
 showmonth = nextmonth;
 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function last_month(){

var lastmonth = showmonth - 1;
if (lastmonth < 1) {
   lastmonth = 12;
   showyear = showyear - 1;
 }
 showmonth = lastmonth;

 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="initialCalendar();">
<div id="showCalendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

calendar_start.php

```
<?php
$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showmonth);
$showyear = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showyear);

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6 - (date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, $day_count,$showyear))));

echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" 
value="Previous Month" onClick="javascript:last_month();"></div';
echo '<div class="show_month">' . $showmonth . '/' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" 
value="Next Month" onClick="javascript:next_month();"></div';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Tue</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';

/* Previous Month Filler Days */
if ($pre_days != 0) {
for($i = 1 ; $i<=$pre_days;$i++) {
echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
}
}

/* Current Month */
for($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {
echo '<div class="cal_day">';
echo '<div class="day_heading">' . $i . '</div>';
echo '</div>';

}
/* Next Month Filler Days */
if ($post_days != 0) {
for ($i=1; $i<=$post_days; $i++) {
 echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
}
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

here is the css

calCss.css

```
#calendar_wrap {
width: 924px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
.title_bar {
width: 100%; 
height: 30px;
}
.previous_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: left;
}
.show_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
.next_month {
float: left;
width: 308px;
height: 30px;
text-align: right;
}
.week_days {
width: 100%;
}       
.days_of_the_week  {
float: left;
width: 14%;
text-align: center;
}      
.cal_day {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
width: 128px;
height: 95px;
background-color: #9C9;
}
.day_heading {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 40px;
height: 16px;
padding: 6px;
color: #000;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
}    
.openings {
width: 100%;
clear:left;
text-align: center;
}
.non_cal_day {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
width: 128px;
height: 95px;
background-color: #CCC;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Can anyone see anything? any help would be great, what errors do i need to show in the google developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file calendar_start.php Line 14 and Line 17, you did not close div correctly
you write . So your Echo block will be like this

```
echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" 
value="Previous Month" onClick="javascript:last_month();"></div>';
echo '<div class="show_month">' . $showmonth . '/' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" 
value="Next Month" onClick="javascript:next_month();"></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Tue</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_the_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

hope this will help

Comment: You absolute legend, thanks so much! Take care have a great week.